# The security token could not be authenticated or authorized

Tags: c#, apache, web-services, wcf, cxf

I need to consume a web service a Apache CXF 2.6 web service from .net client. The headers i'm sending in my requests are like this (captured with fiddler):

```
<soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken></wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <ds:Signature ></ds:Signature>
```

and the service responses:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
        <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">ns1:FailedAuthentication</faultcode>
        <faultstring>The security token could not be authenticated or authorized</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
```

This is my .config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="myCustomBinding">
          <security allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" enableUnsecuredResponse="true"
            authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" securityHeaderLayout="Strict"
            includeTimestamp="false" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
            requireSignatureConfirmation="true" />
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" messageVersion="Soap11">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" requireClientCertificate="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>    
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And this is what i've done so far in my code where i implement my proxy object:

```
    public ConfigureProxy()
{

    try {


        CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding("myCustomBinding");
        DnsEndpointIdentity oDNSEndPoint = new DnsEndpointIdentity(DNS);    
        EndpointAddress oEndPoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("Service"), oDNSEndPoint, new AddressHeaderCollection());   
        StoreLocation oStore = StoreLocation.LocalMachine;

        this.p_CanalProxy = new WSREACXFServiceClient(customBinding, oEndPoint);

        ClientCredentials oCred = this.p_CanalProxy.ClientCredentials;

        oCred.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(oStore, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "thumpr");

        if (oCred.ClientCertificate == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("client cert ");

        oCred.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "thumpr sever cert");

        if (oCred.ServiceCertificate == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("cert server ");

        oCred.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
        oCred.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        p_CanalProxy = null;


    } finally {

    }
}
```

But based on the samples i've got and it suppose to work it needs to be like this:

```
<soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security>
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken></wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        <ds:Signature ></ds:Signature>                                      
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken></wsse:BinarySecurityToken>   <!-- repeated -->
        <xenc:EncryptedKey></xenc:EncryptedKey>
```

please does anybody help me?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the response, it looks like something goes wrong with your certificate. You can check whether the certificate can be authenticated by the service side.

If you could not interact with service hosted server, try to use some SOAP client (e.g. SoapUI) with the same certificate to see what's the response. And check what's the difference between the working SOAP Client request and your raw request message.